# Django changing user created data to another user?

Tags: django

I am having a conceptual issue in my Django project.

In my scenario I have a sales team, this sales team unfortunately has high turn-over. The database works like this:

Salesman Alex (user_id PK) -> has_many Clients (user_id FK) -> has_many Jobs -> has_many Notes

So I am trying to structure my model with the above relationship. However, what I can't wrap my head around is what if Salesman Alex and Salesman Bob SWAP clients? What if Alex quits? The obvious answer would be to update the user_id, however, I have been reading that causes major issues.

Any insight into this would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should maybe think to use [ManyToMany relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) between Salesman and Clients, because, as you post, Salesman can have many Clients and Clients can have many Salesman.

Comment: So in the model I have: user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  How to I make that a ManytoMany relationship?

Comment: Check the link I posted from the Django docs, it'll explain better than me.

Comment: I think I am getting it! Thanks.

Comment: Just gave it a roll and now the accounts are not associated to any user.

Comment: I answered as a conceptual issue as you stated, understandable as if you are starting to desing your app, I hope you are not making major changes to the database if it has data on it. But you mention in your comment accounts and user, when in the question the models are Salesman and Clients. Are those models Account and User?

Comment: Django creates a new table to store the relationship between the model on ManyToManyField, so existing records on ForeignKey will lose their relation. Tha's why you should design your models before entering data to the database.